# VS extension does not pop up sign in dialog

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, vsix, vs-extensibility

I am developing a VS 2015 extension that should connect to VSTS (VisualStudio.com) and pull out backlog items.

The code below works in a console app but not in VSIX project. I call it from a menu item in Team menu (`IDM_MENU_TEAM_FOUNDATION_CLIENT`).

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;
...
public WorkItem GetItems(int itemId) {
    var myCredentials = new VssClientCredentials();
    var vstsConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri(@"https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/"), myCredentials);
    var vstsClient = vstsConnection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
    var workItem = vstsClient.GetWorkItemAsync(itemId).Result;

    return workItem;
}
```

I believe the issue is that the console app can call the sign in screen without any issues. The VS 2015 Experimental Instance, where the VSIX code runs, does not. My research so far does not point to anything useful.

Is there a proper way to connect to VSTS from Visual Studio Extension? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code like this:

```
private void GetWorkItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
             {  
                 var w = GetItems(123);
                 MessageBox.Show(w.Url);
             });

        }

 public WorkItem GetItems(int itemId)
        {
            var myCredentials = new VssClientCredentials();
            var vstsConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri(@"https://xxx.visualstudio.com/"), myCredentials);
            var vstsClient = vstsConnection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
            var workItem =  vstsClient.GetWorkItemAsync(itemId).Result;

            return workItem;
        }
```